# Using UIButton for In App Purchasing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton, in-app-purchase

I am wondering if there is some way to make an iPhone application where when a user clicks a UIButton, it to display an alert box about the item and then gives the user an option to purchase it.  I see a lot of documentation on Apple's site regarding creating a view to store all of the choices of what to buy, but I don't really want to create my application this way.  In addition, do I need to have my app in the app store before I can add in-app-purchasing, or can I do it before?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I am attempting to make the purchase "Non-Consumable", if it makes any difference in how the button would be set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way a user makes the purchase is irrelevant and can be anything you want. The real challenge is getting the in-app purchasing up and running.

Comment: Hi Jonathan: Thanks for your reply!  Do you have any suggestions of where to start for getting in-app purchasing up and running?  I have read through the documentation, but it hasn't been too much help.

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but my impression is that it is a pain in the ass. I would probably recommend Urban Airship (http://urbanairship.com/); they say that they make it painless to set up push notifications and in-app purchase. I've never used them, but I've heard a lot of great things about them. The best of luck to you!